# ExtJs Grid heights and scroll bars eurgh

Tags: extjs4, height, scrollbar, viewport

I have a quite a complicated layout for my application, using borders, vbox's and hbox's which all seem to fit quite well except for one annoyance. The bottom of the grid in the southern region is not behaving. I want the grid to take up the height of the panel when the browser is above minHeight/maximized but at the moment it look like this:

[image]

And when the browser is shrunk (but not below min size) it looks like this and I am unable to get to the bottom of the grid scrollbar :(

[image]

You can see the scrollbar cut of (probable min height on the viewport/grid issue) but not sure how to fix this can someone spot what I need to do resolve these two issues? Code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../app.js"></script>
<!-- script to warn users when leaving page -->
<?php
$db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
$result = $db->query("select ERROR_ID, ERROR_DESCRIPTION, EMAIL_CONTENT, to_char(\"TIMESTAMP\", 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as TIMESTAMP, READ from PI_EMAIL_ERROR where \"TIMESTAMP\" = ( select max(\"TIMESTAMP\") from PI_EMAIL_ERROR ) and READ = 0 and rownum = 1")->FetchAll();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var container = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport',{
        id: 'mainWindow',
        minWidth: 800,
        minHeight: 640,
        layout:'fit',
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function() {
                this.setSize(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());                    
            },
            resize: function(){
                var programGrid = Ext.getCmp('programList');
                if(this.getHeight() < this.minHeight){
                    console.log("Height: ", this.getHeight());
                    console.log("minHeight: ", this.minHeight);
                    console.log("Grid old height: ", programGrid.height);
                    programGrid.height = (this.minHeight - programGrid.height)-18;
                    this.setSize(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
                    console.log("Grid new height: ", programGrid.height);
                } else {
                    programGrid.height = 380;
                }
            }
        },
        defaults: {
            //collapsible: true, //Add this to true later maybe impliment a lock sam
            //when viewport scrolled up, background shows a login.
            split: true,
            rezisable: false
        },
        items:[{
            layout: 'border',
            //height: 640,
            //minHeight: 640,
            items: [
                {
                    //This panel holds the file menu strip and the show combo                    
                    border: false,
                    region: 'north',
                    height: 92,
                    bodyStyle:'background: #DFE8F6;',
                    /******Toolbar*******/
                    tbar: [
                    /****File Button****/
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: window.samlanguage.file,
                            width: 60,
                            handler: function(btn){

                            },
                            menu: [
                                {
                                    text: window.samlanguage.refreshlist,
                                    action: 'refreshGrid',
                                    icon: '../assets/images/refresh.png',
                                    handler: function(btn){

                                    }
                                },{

                                    text: window.samlanguage.settings,
                                    icon: '../assets/images/settings.png',
                                    action: 'spawnSettings',
                                    handler: function(Btn){
                                    }
                                },{

                                    text: window.samlanguage.compose,
                                    icon: '../assets/images/mail--plus.png',
                                    action: 'spawnEmail',
                                    handler: function(Btn){
                                        Ext.create('APP.view.core.forms.Emailform').show();
                                    }
                                },{

                                    text: window.samlanguage.logout,
                                    action: 'logout',
                                    icon: '../assets/images/exit.png',
                                    handler: function(){

                                    }
                                }

                            ]
                        },
                    /****Help Button****/
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: window.samlanguage.help,
                            width: 60,
                            handler: function(btn){

                            },
                            menu: [
                                {
                                    text: window.samlanguage.contents,
                                    icon: '../assets/images/contents.png',
                                    action: 'spawnContents',
                                    handler: function(btn){

                                    }
                                },{

                                    text: window.samlanguage.license,
                                    icon: '../assets/images/licence.png',
                                    handler: function(btn){
                                        var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"<b>Retrieving</b> licensing information..."});
                                        myMask.show();
                                        Ext.Ajax.request({
                                            url: '../License/read',
                                            method: 'post',
                                            //params: values,
                                            success: function(response){
                                                myMask.hide();
                                                var numusers = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                                                Ext.create('APP.view.core.forms.License', {numusers: numusers.numusers}).show();

                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                },{

                                    text: window.samlanguage.about,
                                    icon: '../assets/images/about.png',
                                    //action: 'spawnAbout',
                                    handler: function(btn){
                                        Ext.Msg.show({
                                            title:'About us',                                                
                                            buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                                            icon: 'perceptiveLogo'
                                        });
                                    }
                                }

                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    items: [{
                        //Comboform with userlist
                        xtype: 'Comboform',
                        bodyStyle:'background: #DFE8F6;',
                        border: false
                    }]

                }//End north region (header) region
                ,{
                    region:'center',
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align : 'stretch',
                    items: [
                        {
                            //Add the userlist grid
                            title: 'Currently showing all users',
                            //id: 'usergridList',
                            height: 290,
                            minHeight: 290,
                            border: false,
                            xtype: 'Allusers'
                        },
                        {
                            //Add the allprograms grid
                            title: 'Program Access Permissions',
                            border: false,
                            height: 380,
                            minHeight: 380,
                            //height: 'auto',
                            xtype: 'Allprograms'
                        }
                    ]

                } //End center (body) region
                ,{
                    region:'east',
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align : 'stretch',
                    split: true,
                    //collapsible: true,
                    width: 240,
                    minWidth: 240,
                    maxWidth: 240,
                    //title: 'User Actions',
                    listeners: {
                        /*collapse: function() {
                         this.setTitle("User management");
                         },
                         expand: function() {
                         this.setTitle("User Actions");
                         },
                         click: function() {
                         return false;
                         },*/
                        afterrender: function(){
                            this.splitter.disable();
                        }
                    },
                    //height: 300
                    items :[
                        {
                            title: 'User Actions',
                            border: false,
                            height: 168,
                            xtype: 'Useractionsform'

                        },
                        {
                            title: 'View Audit',
                            border: false,
                            height: 122,
                            xtype: 'Auditform'
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'Program Access',
                            border: false,
                            height: 380,
                            minHeight: 340,
                            xtype: 'Programactionsform'
                        }
                    ]
                } //End of east region
                ,{
                    region: 'south',
                    height: 20,
                    bodyStyle:'background: #DFE8F6;',
                    border: false
                }

            ]
        }]
    }).show();
});
</script>
```

Syntax highlighted link:
http://paste.laravel.com/kPr

Thank you kindly
Nathan

Comment: can use set up a jsfiddle example?

Comment: I'll try but not sure how well it will work :)

Comment: I would first remove the grid and replace it with a simple panel so that you can determine whether it's the grid itself that is screwing things up or if it's just that you messed up with the layout config somewhere.

Also I'm not exactly sure what is the purpose of lines 87-97, the resize handler for the viewport.

Comment: @zeke Ok I'll try that and get back to you, lines 87-97? I think that's the help button in the toolbar?

Comment: @zeke The panel does take up the full height for that region either :/

Comment: I want the Program action grid take up the full height of the region it is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to remove the resize event handler completely. It looks like you're trying to  create a 'vbox' layout on your center panel, but you're using 'type: vbox'. Try using this:

```
layout: {
    type: 'vbox'
    align : 'stretch',
    pack  : 'start',
}
```

This was taken from the ExtJS examples (http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/extjs-build/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html). Then you can just add a 'flex' to your child containers instead of a minheight.

Answer (score 1):

I'm referring to lines 87-97 of the syntax highlighted link you posted.

```
    resize: function(){
        var programGrid = Ext.getCmp('programList');
        if(this.getHeight() < this.minHeight){
            console.log("Height: ", this.getHeight());
            console.log("minHeight: ", this.minHeight);
            console.log("Grid old height: ", programGrid.height);
            programGrid.height = (this.minHeight - programGrid.height)-18;
            this.setSize(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            console.log("Grid new height: ", programGrid.height);
        } else {
            programGrid.height = 380;
        }
    }
```

This is the resize handler for the viewport, so every time the browser is resized, this funciton will explicitly set the grid height.  Not sure what the purpose of this code is but it looks like it could be the issue.  Generally you shouldn't need code like this - everything should fit together if you have the layouts set up right, and then you can use minHeight/maxHeight for the grid if you want.  What happens if you just take this code out?

Comment: Thank you, you were both right, adding that layout config seemed to fix the problem. It is appears I was not calling the vbox correctly.